# Calling a method from other class and set the UILabel iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 classes which names are A and B, I have `UIScrollView` with `pagecontroller` in class A and I have a `UILabel` and `NSMutableArray` in B.

I used this event for get `pagecontroller's` page and i am sending number of page to classB for use array's element.

```
//ClassA
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

CGFloat pageWidth = self.imageScrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((self.imageScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;  
ClassB *obj = [[ClassB alloc]init];
[obj changeDiscount:page];

}

//ClassB
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"15",@"25",nil];
}


-(void) changeDiscount:(int)currentPagePresentation{

NSLog(@"currentI = %i",currentPagePresentation);

_discountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Discount",[numbers objectAtIndex:currentPagePresentation]];

}
```

I can call the `changeDiscount` method but array is coming `null` every time and I can't set the string to label.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your answer and advice.

Comment: Why are you recreating the ClassB object every time on scrollViewDidScroll? Also, is ClassB a view controller? If yes, it should not be instantiated every time like this, you probably want to use a navigation controller or a segue.

Comment: Everything! I don't think you are doing this correctly. if you are doing it right, viewDidLoad is called once a view is loaded. And your view is not never loaded! And none of your elements are initialised. You can force load it by [ClassB view] immediately after intitializaton of class B

Comment: You clearly lack basic understanding over Cocoa Framework. So why don't you take your time and read [ViewController Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). Between, viewDidLoad is not a good place to initialise your array. Do it in init, if you want it to have it initialised right from the beginning.

Comment: where are you initialising discountArray?

Comment: I am sorry, i edited my question. there is no discountArray. it is numbers.

Comment: @JeslyVarghese lol, easy bro. although I couldn't agree more with your comment, you can say it a bit more nicely! aha.

Comment: @Pavan: :) Happen to believe in SOF rules.

Comment: @TwentyThr23 dude you really need to understand what you're doing first before posting code like this. Check everyone's answers and hopefully you come to the conclusion that you're doing something egregiously wrong. Take time to read basic concepts of View Controllers and you'll find that you will become better at programming.

Comment: Thank you all i will try your answers and i will tell you

Comment: @TwentyThr23 No twenty, there is only one way to do this, Fix your code and implement it the right way. Get rid of your existing code and sort it out once and for all. Don't add more code on top of your existing code which is incorrect, why not start correctly so that you have a solid code foundation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your `_discountLabel.text`'s string is equal to `null` is because the `numbers` array that you are accessing has not even been initialised.

The reason why your `numbers` array has not been initialised is because the `viewDidLoad` method only gets called as the method states: `WHEN the view has loaded` ;)

If you want to access the array after creating an instance of your class, its best to setup the `numbers` array in an init method or so.

All you've done is:

```
//This creates a new instance of your second class B.
ClassB *obj = [[ClassB alloc]init];

//Youre trying to access the numbers array when you havent even loaded the view
//All you've done is create an instance of it and then calling a method with an empty numbers array.
[obj changeDiscount:page];
```

And that doesn't sit well with your existing code. Please continue to read to understand why.

You also definitely don't want to be creating new instances of your class every time your scroll view delegate method is called. I highly suggest you revisit that code and find an appropriate place for that code.

**Solution**

1. I suggest you revise the view controllers programmers guide on the apple website before doing anything else.
2. Follow step 1.
3. Follow step 1 again.
4. Then something you can do is:

**Method 1: - lazy method** In class B you could create an instance method like so:

```
//.h
-(void)setupArray;

//.m
-(void)setupArray{
      numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"15",@"25",nil];
}

//Then you can do something like this in class a
ClassB *obj = [[ClassB alloc]init];
[obj setupArray];
[obj changeDiscount:page];
```

**Method 2: more appropriate** If you want to do it in one go you can do this, and create an init method.

```
//.h 
//in your Class B .h file you create an instance method like so:
-(void)init;

//.m file 
-(id)init{
  self=[super init];
  if(self)
     numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"15",@"25",nil];
  return self;
}

//Then in your class a method you can do this:
//Like before.
ClassB *obj = [[ClassB alloc]init];
[obj changeDiscount:page];
```

Comment: Yes, I believe so. The op asked why his string was producing an output of `null` and this answer explains that. Anyway, I just had to point this out, soon as the OP provides us with more information I will be more than happy to add more information to correct his output.

Comment: Would be nicer if you tell him how to do it the right way. Obviously he got it all wrong.

Comment: @JeslyVarghese Yeah man, but thats crazy, writing all the code for him wouldn't help him in the future! eeks! his question will mean we have to cover a lot of ground!

Comment: *Sighs*, I've ended up writing the code out aha. @JeslyVarghese lol

Comment: i would love some syntactic sugar. :) numbers = [[15,25]mutableCopy]

Comment: @Pavan Code or not, i admire the way you handled the situation.  This is what makes good leaders.  God Bless.

Comment: @BriOnH Oh, well that was unexpected! I don't know which situation you're referring to but thank you for the nice comment man. Have a good one.

Comment: @Pavan i tried your solution,it is working.Thanks a lot.In my code i added elements with my hand, but in my real code, elements are coming from my service and i am parsing and adding my array for (NSDictionary *entry in productList) {    
            [numbers addObject:[entry objectForKey:@"DiscountAmount"]];
        } if i add elements like that, how can i use numbers array in changeDiscount method? I know, i had to tell before :) sorry my bad english.

Comment: @TwentyThr23 Thats very annoying. Please dont go around the bush when you are asking a question, next time POST everything so you dont waste other people's time. My answer answers your original question. As for webservices, please check out AFNetworking api, and read up on View controller's and webservice tutorials from AFNetworking so that you can build your project correctly; then if you have any questions regarding specific problems after having it tried out yourself then please post another question.

Comment: @Pavan i handled like that, i insert my element in database, and i selected when call setupArray method. Yeah i know, i am really sorry, i wasted your time. I am really grateful your answers and advices.Btw when i call changeDiscount method, _discountLabel.text is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are a few things causing issues here:

You are creating an instance of `ClassB` within the scope of `scrollViewDidScroll` of `classA`.
As soon as that method completes, that new object will be deallocated.

`ClassB` initialises the numbers array in `viewDidLoad`. This method will be called only when a `UIViewController` subclass loads it’s UIView, so `ClassB` must be a `UIViewControlle`r subclass and you need to have presented it.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is called when you first time access view property of that `viewController`.until then view is nil.
So your `numbers array` wont be initialised because you are calling `changeDiscount` method before `viewDidLoad` is executed.

So, move the initialising from viewDidLoad to init or initWithNib.

```
-(id)init{
  self=[super init];
  if(self)
     numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"15",@"25",nil];
  return self;
}
```

Comment: The array you're talking about `numbers` and the array the OP is talking about `discountsArray` are different. He's asking why when calling the method does the text/string that is logged produce `null`.